# Android/Java - Execute alert when AsyncTask finishes?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to execute an alert when a user is unable to login to their account. That said, when I try to accomplish this with the code below, I'm thrown the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
> thread Thread[AsyncTask #1,5,main] that has not called
> Looper.prepare()

How can I fix this? See my code below.

**LoginActivity**

```
 private class MyNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
       
      @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("username", "admin");
                    jsonObject.put("password", "test#5Q");
    
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
                // put your json here
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/custom-plugin/login")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
    
                Response response = null;
                try {
                    response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String resStr = response.body().string();
                    Log.i("The response is", String.valueOf(response));
                    int responseCode = response.code();
                    Log.i("Check response code", String.valueOf(responseCode));
    
                    if (responseCode == 200) {
    
    
                        Log.i("We're logged in!", String.valueOf(responseCode));
    
                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
    
    
                }
    
                    if (responseCode == 500) {
    
    
                        Log.i("User or pass incorrect.", String.valueOf(responseCode));
    
    
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Oops!");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Your username or password is incorrect. Please check your credentials and try again.");
                       
                        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
    
    
                    }
    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
    
                }
    
                return null;
            }

}

    public void launchDashboard (View v) {

       new MyNetwork().execute();

    }
```

Comment: Use `onPostExecute ` for processing the data & performing UI based ops. Check example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android-asynctask-example-and-explanation

Comment: You are creating a Handler object in somewhere in the code that you haven't shared. Could you share the whole AsyncTask implementation?

Comment: @Kozmotronik sorry about that - accidentally cropped out the other bits! See edit. AsyncTask is executed by a button ("Login").

Comment: So `MyNetwork` is an inner class? You are trying to show an alertdialog from within a background thread. This is not allowed, you must post UI related code to the main thread's queue. But I still don't see where you defined the handler object, do you define a handler? Because the error message you shared is related to it.

Comment: Did you know that the AsyncTask was [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)? Do you insist in using it or you would look for other background processing alternatives?

Comment: I was able to fix my error @Kozmotronik -- but no, didn't no AsyncTask was deprecated! What's the newer course of action? :)

Comment: There are plenty of options for background processing: Plain threads, [Executors](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor), [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler), [ThreadPoolExecutors](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor) and so on. So you can pick one based on your need. Also I recommend you to have a look at the Google's [Processes and threads guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix the above error by wrapping my AlertDialog in:

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

}
```